# Screen repeatedly flashing (reloading?) during an In-app billing screen/activity

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I implemented the example from Android on how to implement the `In-App Billing` (IAB).  Below is one of the 10 classes I had to add to my code to make this work.  I thought I had it working but when I test it on a phone and navigate the app to the below `BibleStudy` activity, the screen loads and then starts "flickering" or possibly reloading the screen over and over and over so it looks like the screen is just flashing over and over.

I don't fully understand the IAB process in this class (and the other 9 classess, for that matter) so I am a little confused on where the error is in my below code.

So my question is, what is it in my below code that is make my activity continually flicker when it loads?

```
public class BibleStudy extends SwarmActivity {

    static final String SKU_SPREADSHEET = "spreadsheet";

    boolean mIsPurchased = false;

    TextView title, link;
    Button purchaseBtn;

    Context c;

    IabHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.biblestudy);

        c = this;

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = a + b + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k;

        // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.    " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.problem1) + " " + result);
                    return;
                }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });

        if(mIsPurchased == true) {
            purchaseBtn.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.thankyou2));
            title.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.thankyou));
            purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alreadyOwned();
                }
            });
        } else {
            title.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.biblestudy));
            purchaseBtn.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.purchaseBtn));
            purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                // User clicked the "Download NOW!" button.
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String payload = "";
                    test(payload);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void alreadyOwned() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alreadyowned);

        TextView tv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        tv.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.alreadyowned));

        dialog.show();
    }

    public void test(String payload) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_SPREADSHEET, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }

    // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own.
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.failedtoquery) + " " + result);
                return;
            }

            /*
             * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
             * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
             * verifyDeveloperPayload().
             */

            Purchase spreadsheetPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SPREADSHEET);

            mIsPurchased = (spreadsheetPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(spreadsheetPurchase));

            updateUi();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if(!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

        /*
         * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
         * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
         * 
         * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and 
         * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the 
         * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on 
         * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
         * random string you originally generated.
         *
         * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
         * 
         * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
         *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
         * 
         * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
         *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on 
         *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
         * 
         * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
         * installations is recommended.
         */

        return true;
    }

    // Callback for when a purchase is finished
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if(result.isFailure()) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + result);
                return;
            }

            if(!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.error2));
                return;
            }

            else if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_SPREADSHEET)) {
                // this appears to the user immediately after purchasing.
                alert(c.getResources().getString(R.string.purchased));
                mIsPurchased = true;
                updateUi();
            }
        }
    };

    // updates UI to reflect model
    public void updateUi() {

        if(mIsPurchased == true) {
            link.setClickable(true);
            link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            String a = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At8avx-xtho6dHhkVzRUNkpJWFBNeGc4S3U1X0k0RFE&usp=sharing'>here</a>";
            String b = c.getResources().getString(R.string.link1) + " ";
            String e = " " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.link3);
            String d = b + a + e;
            link.setText(Html.fromHtml(d));

            Intent intent = new Intent(BibleStudy.this, BibleStudy.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    void complain(String message) {
        alert("Error: " + message);
    }

    void alert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setMessage(message);
        bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        bld.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using right base64EncodedPublicKey from given in the google developer console.

I have seen your code and have some code may be it will solve your error.
You haven't put this code in your activity,please try to add this in your activity.but if in case it will not work then don't remove it, it will not effect your code but it is required for in-app-billing.

// you can replace BibleActivity java file with this one.
BibleActivity.java:

```
public class BibleStudy extends SwarmActivity {

    static final String SKU_SPREADSHEET = "spreadsheet";

    boolean mIsPurchased = false;

    TextView title, link;
    Button purchaseBtn;

    Context c;

    IabHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.biblestudy);

        c = this;

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = a + b + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k;

        // Some sanity checks to see if the developer (that's you!) really
    // followed the
    // instructions to run this sample (don't put these checks on your app!)
    if (base64EncodedPublicKey.contains("CONSTRUCT_YOUR")) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Please put your app's public key in MainActivity.java. See README.");
    }
            // add your packageName here
    if (getPackageName().startsWith("add_your_package_name_here")) {
        // throw new
        // RuntimeException("Please change the sample's package name! See README.");
    }

        // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.    " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.problem1) + " " + result);
                    return;
                }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });

        if(mIsPurchased == true) {
            purchaseBtn.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.thankyou2));
            title.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.thankyou));
            purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alreadyOwned();
                }
            });
        } else {
            title.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.biblestudy));
            purchaseBtn.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.purchaseBtn));
            purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                // User clicked the "Download NOW!" button.
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String payload = "";
                    test(payload);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void alreadyOwned() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alreadyowned);

        TextView tv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        tv.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.alreadyowned));

        dialog.show();
    }

    public void test(String payload) {
      // if device is not supported
       if (!mHelper.subscriptionsSupported()) {
            complain("Subscriptions not supported on your device yet. Sorry!");
       return;
       }

        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_SPREADSHEET, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    }

    // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own.
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.failedtoquery) + " " + result);
                return;
            }

            /*
             * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
             * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
             * verifyDeveloperPayload().
             */

            Purchase spreadsheetPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SPREADSHEET);

            mIsPurchased = (spreadsheetPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(spreadsheetPurchase));

            updateUi();
        }
    };

  // replace your onActivityResult() with this one.

   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
            + data);

    if (mHelper == null)
        return;

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

    /** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

        /*
         * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
         * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
         * 
         * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and 
         * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the 
         * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on 
         * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
         * random string you originally generated.
         *
         * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
         * 
         * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
         *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
         * 
         * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
         *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on 
         *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
         * 
         * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
         * installations is recommended.
         */

        return true;
    }

    // Callback for when a purchase is finished
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if(result.isFailure()) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + result);
                return;
            }

            if(!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                complain("An error has occurred.  We apologize for the inconvenience.  " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.error2));
                return;
            }

            if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_SPREADSHEET)) {
                // this appears to the user immediately after purchasing.
                alert(c.getResources().getString(R.string.purchased));
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
                mIsPurchased = true;
                updateUi();
            }
        }
    };

// Called when consumption is complete it is required for the console to verify transaction consume is completed. 
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase
                + ", result: " + result);

        // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we
        // consume,
        // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than
        // one
        // sku, you probably should check...
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in
            // our
            // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas
            // tank a bit
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
            mTank = mTank == TANK_MAX ? TANK_MAX : mTank + 1;
            // saveData();
            alert("You filled 1/4 tank. Your tank is now "
                    + String.valueOf(mTank) + "/4 full!");
        } else {
            complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        // updateUi();
        // setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};


    // updates UI to reflect model
    public void updateUi() {

        if(mIsPurchased == true) {
            link.setClickable(true);
            link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            String a = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At8avx-xtho6dHhkVzRUNkpJWFBNeGc4S3U1X0k0RFE&usp=sharing'>here</a>";
            String b = c.getResources().getString(R.string.link1) + " ";
            String e = " " + c.getResources().getString(R.string.link3);
            String d = b + a + e;
            link.setText(Html.fromHtml(d));

            Intent intent = new Intent(BibleStudy.this, BibleStudy.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    void complain(String message) {
        alert("Error: " + message);
    }

    void alert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setMessage(message);
        bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        bld.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.